# how to bind img src attribute to dynamic url in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on a Vue project, actually I am trying to bind img src attribute to data value and then I am using a setInterval function to change the url dynamically everytime the function is being called but when I run the page, I am getting an error like

> Property or method "source" is not defined on the instance but
> referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
> either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> found in

so my question is how I could make this kind of binding and see the image changes when the related function is being called by setInterval function

My code is

```
<template>
  <v-card elevation="5" class="mx-auto mt-2" shaped max-width="800">
    <v-img
      class="white--text align-end"
      gradient="to bottom left, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(255,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"
      height="500px"
      aspect-ratio="1.7"
      :src="this.source"
    >
      <v-card-title class="overline">
        <span class="red--text darken-4">
          LIVE
          <v-icon class="red--text darken-4 ma-2" size="3">mdi-circle</v-icon>
        </span>SULTANBEYLI, ISTANBUL | 06/13/2020 - 13.35 PM
      </v-card-title>
    </v-img>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Camera",
  sockets: {
    frames(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  mounted() {
     setInterval(() => {
        this.ex += 1;
        console.log(this.source)


    }, 60000); 
  },
  data: () => ({
    ex: "1",
  })
};
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I edited with the code. @GabrielWillemann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do a minimal example:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="image" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    image: null,
    imageCode: 1,
  }),
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (this.imageCode == 1) {
        this.image =
          'https://smaller-pictures.appspot.com/images/dreamstime_xxl_65780868_small.jpg';
        this.imageCode = 2;
      } else {
        this.image =
          'https://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png';
        this.imageCode = 1;
      }
    }, 2000);
  },
};
</script>
```

Probably the problem of your code is type of "ex" variable. Try this with integer value:

```js
  data: () => ({
    ex: 1,
    source: "http://aua.0xseck.fun/tr/1/1.jpg"
  })
```

Other thing, try to declare in template without "this":

```
<v-img :src="source"></v-img>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, the problem caused by the type of ex variable, I just missed that point to change as integer value. :)

Comment: Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)